# Recursive JavaScript Promises (auto paging an API)

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, es6-promise

I have a paged API that I need to automatically fetch each page of results.

I have constructed the following recursive promise chain, which actually gives me the desired output. I have renamed the traditional resolve to outer to try and wrap my head around it a little more but I am still confused at how passing the outer function into the nested .then is the magic sauce that is allowing this to work?

I thought I knew Promises well but obviously not!

```
  protected execute<T>(httpOptions): Promise<AxiosResponse | T> {
    const reqObject: HttpConfig = {
      ...httpOptions,
      baseURL: this.config.baseUri,
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.config.apiKey}` },
    };

    return new Promise((outer, reject) => {
      axios
        .request<T>(reqObject)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.headers.link) {
            const pagingObject: PagingObject = this.getPagingObject(res);
            this.pagedListResponses = this.pagedListResponses.concat(res.data);
            if (pagingObject.last) {
              this.execute<T>({
                url: pagingObject.next,
              }).then(outer);
            } else {
              outer(this.pagedListResponses as any);
            }
          } else {
            outer("No paging header found");
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => reject(err));
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do you need all the pages at once, or when scrolling etc?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Your method appears to never initialise `this.pagedListResponses`, which will be a source of bugs if you call `execute` multiple times. Use a local variable instead.

Comment: It is initialised in the constructor of the class that this code is within.

Comment: Any questions about my answer?

Answer (score 1):

### **TL:DR**

As you add more and more Promises via recursion they pile up like the skin of an onion. When each is resolved and `.then()` is called, the Promises are removed from the inside out until there are none left.

### [**Promise Chaining**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining)

When a Promise object is created within the *Resolve* handler
of another Promise both Promises are settled in an inside-out order. Additionally, when *chaining* is used through
the Promise instance methods (`.then()`, `.catch()`, .`always()`, etc), the chaining methods take priority and are
executed before the outermost Promise object resolves.

Perhaps better explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30688337/9078341).

Your code creates the Axios Promise  within the Resolve handler of the outer construced Promise Object. The
AxiosPromise's `.then()` will execute prior to the outer Promise finally settling. After that happens the result is passed through the outer Promise object with no modification or processing. Basically a *no-op*.

That is why the wrapper Promise ([explicit-construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it))
is unecessary and discouraged - it is a waste of time and resources that provides no benefit in this code.

With recursion in the mix, Promise objects just keep getting piled on.

So (for now) a reference to that outer Promise object is returned from the `.execute()` method. But when/how is it settled (resolved or rejected)?

1. The Axios Promise resolves with AJAX results

   - If this is a recursive call, this is an inner Promise (even though created with `.then(outer)` which is more confusing in this case)
2. The outer most `.then()` is called with the AJAX results (or rejected with reason)
3. The instance variable `pagedListResponses` is updated with the results
4. if `res.headers.link == true && pageObject.last == true`

   - Recurse & start back at 1 <- **pending** with unsettled Promise(s)
5. else if `res.headers.link == true && pageObject.last == false`

   - resolve the outer most Promise with the `pageListResponses` <- completely **settled**
6. else if `res.headers.link == false && pageObject.last == false`

   - resolve the outer most Promise with "No paging header found" <- completely **settled**
7. Then `then()` method attached to the initial call to `execute()` is called with the `pageListResponses`

   - ex. `this.execute({...}).then(pageList=>doSomethingWithPageOfResults());`

So chaining, using `.then()` midstream, allows us to do some data processing (as you have done) prior to returning an
eventually settled Promise result.

In the recursive code:

```
this.execute<T>({
    url: pagingObject.next,
}).then(outer);
```

The `.then()` call here simply adds a new inner Promise to the chain and, as you realize, is exactly the same as writing:

`.then(result=>outer(result));` [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

### [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

Finally, using [Async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) / [Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) is recommended. It is strongly suggested to [Rewrite Promise code with Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#rewriting_promise_code_with_asyncawait) for complex (or some say *any*) scenarios.
Although still asychronous, this makes reading and rationalizing about the code sequence *much* easier.

Your code rewritten to take advantage of Async/Await:

```
 protected async execute<T>(httpOptions): Promise<T> {
    const reqObject = {
      ...httpOptions,
      baseURL: this.config.baseUri,
      headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${this.config.apiKey}`},
    };
    try {
      const res: AxiosResponse<T> = await axios.request<T>(reqObject);
      if (res) {
        const pagingObject: boolean = this.getPagingObject(res);
        this.pagedListResponses = this.pagedListResponses.concat(res.data);
        if (pagingObject) {
          return this.execute<T>({ url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/todos'});
        } else {
          return this.pagedListResponses as any;
        }
      } else {
        return "No paging header found" as any;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error('Unable to complete request for data.');
    }
  }
```

Here, `async` directly indicates "This method returns a Promise" (as typed). The `await` keyword is used in code only once to wait for the resolution
of the AJAX request. That statement returns the actual result (as typed) as opposed to a Promise object. What happens with a network error? Note the use of `try/catch` here. The `catch` block handles any reject in the nest/chain. You might notice the recursive call has no `await` keyword. It isn't necessary in this case since it is a Promise that just passes along its result. (it's OK to add `await` here but it has no real benefit).

This code is used the same way from the outside:
`this.execute({...}).then(pageList=>doSomethingWithPageOfResults());`

Let me know what gaps you may still have.

Answer (score 0):

Well when you call `this.execute`, it returns a `Promise<AxiosResponse | T>`.

So by calling `.then(outer)`, the response from the recursive `execute` function is being used to resolve your outer promise.

It's basically the same as `this.execute(...).then(response => outer(response))`, if that makes it any clearer.